# Why is first LI shifted downwards in FF and IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, css

I'm working on an HTML5 navigation where I'm using this HTML:

```
<menu>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class=clip>Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class=clip>Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class=clip>Test</a></li>
</menu>
```

This can be seen in [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kMDBy/).

All `LI` elements are displayed as `inline-block`. I'm also giving `inline-block` to links within because I need to provide them particular `line-height`.

This is LESS for the above HTML example

```
menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #eee;

    li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 50px;
        display: inline-block;

        a {
            display: inline-block; // <--- CULPRIT
            border: 1px solid #ccc;

            &.clip {
                width: 1em;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Issues

Above code displays just fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox and Internet Explorer (11 is the one I'm using). FF and IE both display first `LI` shifted down.

If I remove `inline-block` of links, first child's shift disapears, but links don't have appropriate `line-height` nor can I set links' width as they're now displayed `inline`.

### Question

What did I do wrong and how should I resolve this cross-browser way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline blocks are placed on the current base line. The menu has its own, and the lis are aligned there. Add

```
menu li {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

and the stray top margin is gone.

Comment: But why do they seem to have different baseline as they're all contained in the same `menu`?

Comment: Because of the `overflow:hidden` on the `.clip` elements. That manipulates the way the inline-block containers are laid out. You can see the effect, when you give the first one a class `clip`, too. (You could also get rid of the `overflow: hidden` part to fix your problem.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the reason behind but its to do with how different browsers render `inline-block`.

**Solution 1**

You can change `display: inline-block` to `display: block` and use `float: left` to your li elements

```
menu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**Solution 2**

Is the keep `display: inline-block` but add `vertical-align: top`

```
menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: remove the first solution.. because it is alternate solution but does not explain why the first li is down. or make it second solution. (_also no need of display: block_)

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: block; float: left;` to your a tag inside the li // or even inline-block ok. here important is float to left.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kMDBy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you change your css according to this

```
     menu {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        background-color: #eee;
    }

    li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 50px;
        display:inline;
    }

    a {
        display: inline;
        /*CULPRIT border: 1px solid #ccc;*/
    }

        &.clip {
            width: 1em;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
```

[FiddleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/v7DaD/1/)

Answer (score 0):

See this example:
http://www.overpie.com/css/articles/css-vertical-fly-out-menu

I would recommend not to use line-height, as if you have long text, you will have trouble.

Comment: I'm already using `white-space: nowrap` because I'm clipping some items.